# asp.net javascript redirect failure

Tags: javascript, asp.net

From my main app page, Default.aspx I am popping up another page with `window.open`. 
On that page I have a home link as a `HyperLink` that calls a `Javascript` function.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkHome" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lnkHome" NavigateUrl = " " onclick = "javascript:performRedirect()">
```

I am checking if the parent window is still running and if it is just closing this window, If not then redirecting back to the main window.

```
function performRedirect() {
    if (parentExists()) {

        $("a[id$= lnkHome]").attr('href', 'window.close();');
    }
    else {

        $("a[id$= lnkHome]").attr('href', 'Default.aspx');
    }
}
function parentExists() {

    return (window.parent.location === window.location) ? false : true;
}
```

It works, but for some reason check fails and it always redirects me to `Default.aspx` even if calling page is still open. What do I need to change here? Unfortunately I have to use `HyperLink` control. I am using ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: Have you tried `function parentExists() { return window.opener!==null;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check for `window.opener` instead of `window.parent` since you are opening the window using `window.open`

Your `parentExistis` func become this:

```
function parentExists() { 
    return window.opener!==null;
}
```

Or...

```
function parentExists() { 
    return window.opener!==null && window.opener.location.href===window.location.href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah `window.parent` would always give me current window instead of an opener. Your suggestion works on FireFox. I think `window.opener` doesn't have any cross-browser issues?

Comment: I don't believe window.opener has any cross-browser issues. W3 schools claims that it's supported in all browsers. I don't know how reliable W3 schools is, but I don't recall ever seeing any issues with `window.opener`

Comment: Actually I have to take it back as it worked in `FF` but not in `IE`. Just FYI I came up with implementation that works in both: `function parentExists() { 
    return (window.opener && !window.opener.closed);
}`